# Component not rendering with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to navigate and show different components on different route .
so my index.js looks like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

then render function of my Routes component is like

```
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route exact path="/admin/add-product" component={AdminAddProduct}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

so i have navbar component where on clicking i have defined the actions

```
render() {
  return (
    <Router>
       <MDBNavbar color="default-color" dark expand="md">
      <MDBNavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleCollapse} />
      <MDBCollapse id="navbarCollapse3" isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
        <MDBNavbarNav left>
          <MDBNavItem>
            <MDBNavLink to="/">Shop</MDBNavLink>
          </MDBNavItem>

          <MDBNavItem>
            <MDBNavLink to="/admin/add-product">Admin product</MDBNavLink>
          </MDBNavItem>
        </MDBNavbarNav>
      </MDBCollapse>
    </MDBNavbar>
    </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

so initially when i am in  ' / ' i am seeing my Homepage component as i have defined in routes.js file but then when i click on Admin product the routes go to /admin/add-product but then the component is not rendered on screen

If i refresh my page staying on that route then only i am able to see the contents of AdminAddProduct page.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the entire structure of your app, I don't know if this is good advice.  I am assuming you also have an app.js file.

You will need app.js in your index.js file and it should be wrapped the Router.

Your index.js file should look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Notice that `BrowserRouter` is in index.js, not in the Routes component, in this example.

Also, make sure that your Routes component is imported into App.js or write this logic directly in App.js.

```
 <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
   <Route exact path="/admin/add-product" component={AdminAddProduct}/>
 </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be conflict problem depending on you react-router-dom and mdbootstrap version since the react-router-dom version 5.0.0v had a conflict with MDBNavLink component but the issue has been resolved for react-router-dom version 5.0.1v so  try upgrading the react-router-dom version to the latest

```
npm i react-router-dom@latest
```